# Can a UIButton animation continue during a pushViewController transition?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm in the process of making buttons grow and shrink instead of highlight when selected. The goal is to have the button grow when you tap it...and execute two actions simultaneously when released:

1. the screen transition using pushViewController
2. shrink the button back to normal size during the transition

My problem: I can't accomplish 1&2 simultaneously. The release animation seems to be cancelled by the screen transition. The button remains stays at it's large size during the transition.

Screeshots

- normal size feed button in the bottom left [image]
- scaled up feed button, where it gets stuck during screen transition [image]

Animation Methods for buttonPress and buttonRelease:

```
- (void)buttonPress:(UIButton*)button{
    POPSpringAnimation *scaleAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerScaleXY];
    scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(1.5, 1.5)];
    scaleAnimation.springBounciness = 15.f;
    [button.layer pop_addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scaleAnim"];
    button.highlighted = NO;
}


- (void)buttonRelease:(UIButton*)button {
    POPSpringAnimation *scaleAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerScaleXY];
    scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];
    scaleAnimation.springBounciness = 15.f;
    [button.layer pop_addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scaleAnim"];
    button.highlighted = NO;
}
```

Method for attaching animations to the button:

```
- (void)attachAnimationsToButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonRelease:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonRelease:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonRelease:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
}
```

Feed button:

```
 self.feedButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
 [self.feedButton setImage:[UIImage tag_feedButtonImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [self attachAnimationsToButton:self.feedButton];
 [self.feedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showFeed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self addSubview:self.feedButton];
```

Show feed method:

```
- (void)showFeed
{   
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[TAGTabBarController new] animated:NO];
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

-Josh

Comment: Try doing the transition manually instead of using a navigation controller

Comment: @KhanhNguyen thanks but I'm trying to see if there is any way to do it WITH the navigation controller, before making such a drastic change